# .NET Read XML Trace File

Tags: c#, .net, xml, logging

In my .NET application I have an [XmlWriterTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener.aspx), is there any thing in .NET that already aids in reading these files as enumerated models?

I haven't found anything yet and am thinking I'll just need to open the file as read only with a object shared for read and writing so I don't lock the file for further logging then use linq to XML or an XML Reader to read the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to get your hands dirty with LINQ to XML or with Microsoft's [LogParser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274). It's a free tool and it can be integrated with your applications. It has a nice SQL-like language for extracting information.

Comment: Thank you for the input Huske. I figured I would have to and that was my plan. Just wondering if the internet world knew something I hadn't found yet to make it easier.